# How can I get a Layout "ready drawn and attached" callback?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a big problem with a layout in my Android Application. I have a

`RelativeLayout` 
- inside this Layout I will nest a `TableLayout` (at Top) and another `RelativeLayout` (at Bottom)

In my program I fill both layouts (programmatically) with some views - first the `TableLayout` and then the `RelativeLayout`. I need the height from the nested `RelativeLayout` to calculate some things. But I always get the height without the height from the "fresh painted" `TableLayout`.

How can I get a callback (ore something) to recognize that my first layout (`TableLayout`) is finished and "sticks" at the parent layout? Then I determine the correct amount remaining height (of the nested `RelativeLayout`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to override the class TableLayout and override it's methods `onMeasure, onDraw or onAttachedToWindow`

It's not difficult, but a bit tricky to handle when a view is completely drawn on the screen

Check the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int, int)